# What does "belly" mean in Philippians 3:19?

Tags: greek, philippians, anatomy

Many translations of the Bible use the word "belly" in [Philippians 3:19](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Philippians%203:19):

> Their end is destruction, their god is their belly, and they glory in their shame, with minds set on earthly things. (ESV)

The context of the passage doesn't seem particularly focused on food intake, so I was a little surprised that Matthew Henry's [Method of Prayer](http://www.matthewhenry.org/read/esv-corporate/chapter-eight/?page=4#.VdyIxvlVhBc) connects this verse directly to eating:

> Lord, grant that we may not feed ourselves without fear, Jude 1:12(KJV) that we may not make a god of our belly, Philippians 3:19(KJV)

Is the word "belly" here best interpreted specifically in the sense of overeating and gluttony?  Or should it be viewed more generally, more along the lines of "desires of the flesh" or the like?

Comment: Great question! cf. [Rom 16:18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=romans%2016%3A18&version=NRSV;SBLGNT)

Answer (score 5):

**Meaning of κοιλια**

The word used here is κοιλια. Bauer (BDAG) lists three primary meanings<sup>1</sup>:

1. the organ of nourishment
2. womb, uterus
3. seat of inward life, of feelings and desires (functionally equivalent to English heart)

Significantly, Phil 3:19 is explicitly listed under meaning 1, not 3. So according to BDAG, it means stomach as in a organ, not desire.

**Other Usage**

Based on a quick review of the usage in the New Testament, it does appear that the vast majority of occurrences are in reference to a physical body part (stomach or womb):

- Stomach: Matt. 12:40; 15:17; Mk. 7:19; 1 Co. 6:13; Rev. 10:9f
- Womb: Matt. 19:12; Lk. 1:15, 41f, 44; 2:21; 11:27; 23:29; Jn. 3:4; Acts 3:2; 14:8; Gal. 1:15

Although less common, I did find some references that do not seem to be addressing a physical body part (English translation of κοιλια in bold):

- Jn. 7:38 “and let the one who believes in me drink. As the scripture has said, 'Out of the believer's **heart** shall flow rivers of living water.'” (NRSV)
- Rom. 16:18 “For such people do not serve our Lord Christ, but their own **appetites**, and by smooth talk and flattery they deceive the hearts of the simple-minded.” (NRSV)

**Meaning in Context**

If BDAG is accepted, the question of course is what aspect of the stomach Paul has in mind. The question suggested one possibility related to the stomach: “overeating and gluttony.” However I’ll throw out another option: Paul could be referring to Judaizers who demanded adherence to certain dietary laws.

Verses 2 and 3 read: “Beware of the dogs, beware of the evil workers, beware of those who mutilate the flesh! For it is we who are the circumcision, who worship in the Spirit of God and boast in Christ Jesus and have no confidence in the flesh…” (NRSV). Based on the references to ‘those who mutilate the flesh’ and ‘circumcision,’ Judaizers seem to be in view. This is further supported by verses 4b – 6, where Paul explains that he actually has more reasons for confidence in the flesh than they do. He justifies his claim by touting that he is a model Jew, even claiming that he is legally blameless.

Although Philippines does not get into much detail about this group, it is a common theme throughout his letters, and Paul is often opposing those who relied on ‘works of the law’ instead of faith in Christ.<sup>2</sup> Paul’s primarily concerns with the Judaizers’ included their insistence on Jewish dietary restrictions, circumcision, and following festivals.<sup>3</sup>

In verses 12 through 16, Paul urges his readers to move forward in pursuit of resurrection, following the path of faith instead of the Judaizers’ rightness through the law. If verses 17 through 21 are a continuation of Paul’s line of thought, then these verses are closing out his discussion by again specifically address the Judaizers. He emphasizes that the they are “enemies of the cross of Christ” (3:18, NRSV), potentially because they relying on works instead of faith (similarly in Romans 11:28 Paul calls non-believing Jews enemies). Unlike the Judaizers, who establish their identity through the works of the law, Paul reminds his readers that their “citizenship is in heaven” (3:20, NRSV).<sup>4</sup>

Müller also takes this view:

> *(2) Their god is the belly*: although such a description could suit sensualists, people of dissolute character, Paul in Rom. 16:18 designates people like the Judaists, who sow dissension in the churches and are the cause of offence against the doctrine, as people "who serve their own belly." While the New Testament nowhere describes licentiousness as "serving the belly," the Judaists were the people who enforced the observance of all kinds of laws relating to meat and drink, by which they did not do justice to the all-sufficient merits of the cross of Christ. "Touch not and taste note-eat and eat not" became religion to them...*(4) They mind earthly things*: By this not necessarily carnal sins are meant, but the direction of their thoughts towards earthly things, worldly-mindedness, a lige order according to worldy measures. The Judaistic piety makes a god of the belly...for nothing else but earthly-mindedness...<sup>5</sup>

**Conclusion**

If these “enemies of the cross of Christ” (NRSV) in Philippines 3:18 are the same “dogs” (NRSV) in verses 2 and 3, then it could follow that 3:19 is addressing the ‘works of the law’ that these Judaizers demand, namely dietary restrictions and circumcision. In this context, “their god is the belly” (NRSV) could be referring to Jewish dietary laws. The Judaizers are treating their stomach like a god - a god who is either appeased or angered by consumption of certain foods - instead of following Paul's God, who alternately seeks faith. Thus, Paul concludes “their minds are set on earthly things” (3:19, NRSV) - food and circumcision - instead of heavenly things - specifically salvation through Christ and resurrection (3:20f).

---

1. Bauer, Walter, Frederick W. Danker, William F. Arndt, and F. Wilbur Gingrich. A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature, 3rd ed. Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 2000, page 550 (BDAG).
2. Galatians 2:16: “yet we know that a person is justified not by the works of the law but through faith in Jesus Christ. And we have come to believe in Christ Jesus, so that we might be justified by faith in Christ, and not by doing the works of the law, because no one will be justified by the works of the law.” (NRSV)
3. For example: Colossians 2:11, 16 : “In him also you were circumcised with a spiritual circumcision, by putting off the body of the flesh in the circumcision of Christ…Therefore do not let anyone condemn you in matters of food and drink or of observing festivals, new moons, or sabbaths.” Similarly, Galatians 2:11f: “But when Cephas came to Antioch, I opposed him to his face, because he stood self-condemned; for until certain people came from James, he used to eat with the Gentiles. But after they came, he drew back and kept himself separate for fear of the circumcision faction.” Galatians 5:6,11: “For in Christ Jesus neither circumcision nor uncircumcision counts for anything; the only thing that counts is faith working through love... But my friends, why am I still being persecuted if I am still preaching circumcision? In that case the offense of the cross has been removed.”
4. This is argument is easier to buy if one accepts the new perspective.
5. Müller, Jac. J. 1988. The Epistle Of Paul To The Philippians, in The New International Commentary On The New Testament, edited by F. F. Bruce, 130-132. Wm. B. Eerdmans Publishing Company: Grand Rapids, Michigan. Italics original.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,a particular word can be used in several contexts in the Bible, but as regards the word "belly" OR "stomach in Phillipians 3:19...

Phillipians 3:19(NIV): Their destiny is destruction, their god is their stomach, and their glory is in their shame. Their mind is on earthly things.

...could be best interpreted as the "desires of the flesh".

Secondly, before you can understand the Bible, you need to do a proper follow-up on the scriptures before and after such verse or text. So, to justify what I earlier said, when you look at the text following "their god is their stomach", which is "and their glory is in their shame. Their mind is on earthly things", in that context, it could be said as the destiny of those who focus their desires on the flesh will lead to destruction, their glory is in their shame(ie. they feel proud of their shameless acts). Their mind is on earthly things.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the parallelism in
Philippians 3:19

```
Their end        is       destruction,   
their god        is       their belly,   
and they glory   in       their shame,   
with minds       set on   earthly things.
```

Is the word "belly" here best interpreted specifically in the sense of overeating and gluttony?

Not really, Paul is not talking about food but about something else far more important. He talks about end, god, glory and minds.

Or should it be viewed more generally, more along the lines of "desires of the flesh" or the like?

I think so. Belly is paralleled with destruction, shame, and earthly things.

Elsewhere, Paul wrote in Roman 16:

> 17 Now I exhort you, brothers, to consider those causing divisions and obstacles contrary to the teaching that you have learned, and turn away from them. 18For such do not serve our Lord Christ, but their own **belly**; and by smooth talk and flattery they deceive the hearts of the naive.

If you do not serve Christ, you serve your own belly, i.e., your own selfish fleshly desires inspired by Satan.
These activities are earthly, unspiritual, destructive, and shameful.

What does “belly” mean in Philippians 3:19?

It symbolizes Satan. Paul gives a binary choice: either you serve God or you serve your belly/Satan.

Answer (score 0):

Gluttony is a sin. Ask the widow and the orphan. Gluttonous people are rarely thinking of the needs of others.

Pure religion and undefiled before our God and Father is this, to visit the fatherless and widows in their affliction, and to keep oneself unspotted from the world. - James 1:27

For meat destroy not the work of God. All things indeed are pure; but it is evil for that man who eateth with offence.It is good neither to eat flesh, nor to drink wine, nor any thing whereby thy brother stumbleth, or is offended, or is made weak.Hast thou faith? have it to thyself before God. Happy is he that condemneth not himself in that thing which he alloweth.And he that doubteth is damned if he eat, because he eateth not of faith: for whatsoever is not of faith is sin. - Romans 14:20-23

Let your moderation be known unto all men. The Lord is at hand. - Philippians 4:5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).